# I'm telling them/I'll tell them/I'm going to tell them

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

Are these all natural to your native-speaking ears?

1. If you don't pay me right now, **I'm telling them what you did!**
2. If you don't pay me right now, **I'll tell them what you did!**
3. If you don't pay me right now, **I'm going to tell them what you did!**

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, they would all work.

Also, number 2 is the most technically correct, but again, any of them will work.